# My selected items in NavigationDrawer do not change depending on the selected item how to make everything OK?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I click on the item in the navigation drawer it redirects me to another actvitiy but the item I clicked on does not become highlighted. You can see it in the GIF below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM1m0.jpg

MenuActivity.class

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Drawer(toolbar,MenuActivity.this,MenuActivity.this);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Аппараты");
    }
```

void Drawer:

```
public void  Drawer(Toolbar toolbar, Context context, android.app.Activity activity){


    DatabaseReference rootRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference uidRef2 = rootRef2.child("users").child(getUid());
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener2 = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String email = dataSnapshot.child("account").getValue(String.class);
            String Avatar = dataSnapshot.child("Avatar").getValue(String.class);
            Long coinsAmount = dataSnapshot.child("coinsAmount").getValue(Long.class);

            String coinsView = "Баланс: " + coinsAmount;




                if (Avatar.equals("1")) {
                    avatar = (R.drawable.a1);
                }
                if (Avatar.equals("2")) {
                    avatar = (R.drawable.a2);
                }


            IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withName(email)
                    .withEmail(coinsView)
                    .withIcon(avatar);

            AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                    .withActivity(activity)
                    .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.account_header_background)
                    .addProfiles(
                            profile
                    )
                    .build();


               result = new DrawerBuilder()
                    .withActivity(activity)
                    .withToolbar(toolbar)
                    .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Устройства")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.device)
                                    .withIdentifier(1)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Сканер")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.scaner)
                                    .withIdentifier(2)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Магазины")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.shop)
                                    .withIdentifier(3)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Купоны")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.coupons)
                                    .withIdentifier(4)
                    )
                    .addDrawerItems(
                            new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName("Архив Купонов")
                                    .withIcon(R.drawable.oldcoupons)
                                    .withIdentifier(5)
                    )
                    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener((view, i, iDrawerItem) -> {
                        if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1 && !Activity.equals("Menu")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2 && !Activity.equals("Scaner")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DecoderActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 3 && !Activity.equals("Shop")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,ShopActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(iDrawerItem.getIdentifier() == 4 && !Activity.equals("oldCoupons")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,oldCouponsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        return false;
                    })
                    .build();

            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            Objects.requireNonNull(result.getActionBarDrawerToggle()).setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    };
    uidRef2.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener2);




}
```

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.Activities.MenuActivity" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

How to make everything work and be like all normal applications?

I don't even have a clue how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Add below to the code when you select a drawer item.

```
iDrawerItem.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: this method have iDrawerItem no but he has a setSelect and setSelectable but they also do not work